# AngularJs get request with authorization

Tags: angularjs, cors

I am trying to issue a get request that requires authentication but it's not issuing the GET request as I can see in the networks tab in chrome that it's issuing an OPTIONS request and hence getting 404 error?

```
      $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + _this.auth_token;

      $http.get('http://localhost:2337/getFeedbackForm/abcd?format=json')
       .success(function (data, status, headers) {

           blockUI.stop();

           $scope.feedbackForm = data;

       })
       .error(function (data, status, header, config) {

           blockUI.stop();

           $scope.feedbackForm = data;

       });
```

Why it's treating GET request like PUT or POST?

Comment: The `Authorization` header is not a [CORS Safe-listed header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header). It  will trigger an OPTIONS request which must have a successful response or the XHR will be blocked by browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your API request looks like it's built correctly so your Angular code is not the issue.

If you see the OPTIONS request go out but not the GET request, it means that the OPTIONS request failed, so the browser didn't send the GET request. The [MDN docs on preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) explain this behaviour:

> Unlike “simple requests” (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data.

If your server doesn't have CORS enabled for the domain your Angular app is running on, it means it's not accepting requests so the browser doesn't send the GET request.

To solve this, you must enable CORS on your API running at localhost:2337. Since I don't know what your server is built in, here are some options:

- [ExpressJS using the cors() middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)
- [Hapi.js](https://hapijs.com/api#-routeoptionscors)
- [Ruby on Rails by configuring Rack::Cors middleware](https://medium.com/@Nicholson85/handling-cors-issues-in-your-rails-api-120dfbcb8a24)

You can try initially by changing it to allow all requests, and then narrowing it down by domain or route.

Essentially, your server needs to return a header for the OPTIONS request that includes the requesting domain, or everything using the wildcard asterisk:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

More info on [MDN: HTTP Headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is CORS on the back-end side.

More about CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Your back-end needs to accept the 'OPTION' type of HTTP request on all endpoints + add the header to your responses

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

More about header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin